# Moment() gives wrong time

Tags: momentjs

When debugging my moment variable I noticed that the time in my momentobject was not reflecting the expected time.

Time of screenshot was 15:09.

Time on momentobject 15:22.

This is a difference of 13 minutes...

Is this a bug or is there an (maybe not so logic) explanation for this behaviour?

[image: ent]

Comment: Maybe this is about the timezone configured in your server..

Comment: I would expect a difference in hours and not in minutes